# Reading in a data file into an array of objects?

Tags: java, object

I'm having problems reading in my file into an array of objects. I created an if statement so that the lines of data get separated into two different subgroups one is produce and the other is cleaning. But when I run the program the objects that are created are empty. How do I connect the file into the objects? I'm missing something crucial.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Inventory{

    public static void main(String[] args){
         int i=0;
         Product[] pr=new Product[16];
         File InventoryFile=new File("inventory.csv");
         Scanner in=null;
         try{
            in=new Scanner(InventoryFile);
            while(in.hasNext()){
               String line=in.nextLine();
               String[]fields=line.split(",");
               if(fields[0].equals("produce"))
                    pr[i]= new Produce();
               else 
                    pr[i]=new Cleaning();
               i++;
            }
            System.out.println(pr[6]);  
           }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
             System.out.println("Arrgggg"+e.getMessage());
           }    
      }
  }
```

Comment: What is the output/exception you are getting? Why do you feel the objects are empty?

Comment: objects that are created are empty: what do you mean?

Comment: the output is null,0,0,null,0

Comment: can you share your file contents also

Comment: Produce and Cleaning class please? you are just printing pr[6], looks like toString is overridden.

Comment: 15
produce,3554,broccoli,5.99,1
produce,3554,broccoli,5.99,1
produce,3555,carrots,2.23,0.25
produce,3555,carrots,2.23,0.25
produce,3555,carrots,2.23,0.25
cleaning,2345,windex,5.99,1 unit
cleaning,2345,windex,5.99,1 unit
cleaning,2345,windex,5.99,1 unit
cleaning,2345,windex,5.99,1 unit
cleaning,2346,toilet paper,12.99,4 rolls
cleaning,2346,toilet paper,12.99,4 rolls
cleaning,2335,windex,2.25,1 mini sprayer
cleaning,1342,wipes,3.99,10 units
cleaning,1342,wipes,3.99,10 units
produce,3546,lettuce,2.99,0.5

Comment: You are creating the Produce and Cleaning objects, but you are not filling them

Comment: public class Produce extends Product{

 public String toString(){
  return super.toString()+" weight;"+ weight;
  }
 public double weight;

}

Comment: public class Cleaning extends Product{

 public String toString(){
  return super.toString()+"units;"+ units;
  }
 public int units;
 
}

Comment: @Ivan_Stepul Edit your question instead of posting relevant material as comments

Answer (score 3):

Your problem stems from not even setting your varibles in your objects all you haven been doing is making them produce and cleaning but not filled in their fields.

I can not answer further without knowing how you set up your produce, product, and cleaning classes and how they get their varibles filled.

Answer (score 0):

You are not filling your Objects, you are creating, but not filling them. You can create a constructor like this:

```
public Product(String a, int b, int c, String, d, int e)
{
     this.a = a;
     this.b = b;
     this.c = c;
     this.d = d;
     this.e = e;
}
```

and in the extended classes you just call the super constructor.

```
public Produce(String a, int b, int c, String, d, int e)
{
    super(a,b,c,d,e);
}
```

and when you create them call:

```
new Produce(fields[0],Integer.parseInt(fields[1]),Integer.parseInt(fields[2]),fields[3],Integer.parseInt(fields[4]));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're adding your Produce/Cleaning objects in your while loop here

```
if(fields[0].equals("produce"))
                pr[i]= new Produce();
           else 
                pr[i]=new Cleaning();
```

you're just adding new, blank Produce/Cleaning objects into your array.

To fix this, you need to have some getters and setters in your Produce/Cleaning objects classes, so that you can set the values of whatever variables it is you're trying to set (Strings for names of produce/cleaning items? doubles for prices? ints for # in-stock?).

Once you have that, you can give your Produce/Cleaning objects values that will mean something when you try to pull them up again, i.e.

```
if(fields[0].equals("produce"))
                pr[i]= new Produce(fields[1], fields[2], fields[3]); //assuming you make a constructor that takes these values
           else 
                pr[i]=new Cleaning(fields[1], fields[2], fields[3]);
.
.
.
if(pr[i] instanceOf Produce)
                String vegName = pr[i].getName();
                int stock = pr[i].getStock();
                double price = pr[i].getPrice();
```

I'd need to know more about what is in the csv and what you're trying to create with enter code hereyour array to give you more help, but hopefully this is a start.